# How to perform quantize aware training with tensorflow 1.15?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 1.15 due to dependency on multiple other modules and struggling to do quantize aware training. I came across tensorflow_model_optimization, but it works with tensorflow 2.x. Is there any way Quantization can be performed during training with tensorflow 1.15?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot as quantization aware training was introduced in TF 2.0, so please upgrade to 2.x and let us know if you face any issues. as there is no workaround for it in 1.x.